# angular 2 NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using Reactive form pattern in angular 2 project. I would like to populate a container dynamically with answers(answers object is fetched and populated using http call).

Reactive form object structure:

```
public questionDetailForm = this.fb.group({
    type    : ['', Validators.required],
    title   : ['', Validators.required],
    required: [false],
    answers : this.fb.array([])
});
```

helper array to populate 'answers' key of 'questionDetailForm' object:

```
public formArray = <FormArray>this.questionDetailForm.controls['answers'];
```

'formArray' is populated by http call response data:

```
if (response.data.question.answers != null && response.data.question.type_id !== 400 && response.data.question.type_id !== 800) {
    for (const key in response.data.question.answers) {
        if (response.data.question.answers.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           this.formArray.push(new FormControl(response.data.question.answers[key] , Validators.required));
        }
    }
}
```

the problem arises in html file(highlighted in bold):

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlexOffset="10" *ngFor="let answer of **questionDetailForm.controls['answers'];** let i = index" class="base-input-container answer-container">
    <md-input-container fxFlex="70" [ngClass]="{haserror: formErrors.answer && i === answerIndexError}">
       <input mdInput type="text" [formControl]="answer" placeholder="Answer">
    </md-input-container>
    <button type="button" fxFlexOffset="3" class="remove-answer" md-fab mdTooltip="remove answer" (click)="removeAnswer(i)" color="primary"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
</div>
```

I have just updated from angular-cli beta version to 1.0.0. I have not faced the same issue using the beta version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over an `FormArray` try:

```
questionDetailForm.get('answers')
```

Or:

```
questionDetailForm.controls['answers'].controls
```

Comment: thanks a lot...also worked as questionDetailForm.controls.answers.controls

Comment: when i build the project for production i am getting 'Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl''